# Aerospike Record UDF is it atomic?

Tags: lua, atomic, aerospike

Is the Aerospike record UDF atomic?

```
function increment_and_expire(rec, incValue, expireThreshold, currentTime)
      if aerospike:exists(rec) then
          local timesUsed = rec['timesUsed']
          if timesUsed == expireThreshold or rec['validUpto'] < currentTime then
            rec['expired'] = true
        else
            rec['timesUsed'] = timesUsed + incValue
        end
        aerospike:update(rec)
        return 1
    else
        warn("record doesn't exists")
        return -1
    end
end
```

The above Lua function increments the usage of a token and if its not valid anymore, it marks it expired.
Now my doubt is, if  concurrent request comes for the same record and this function is being executed concurrently, would that cause any issues?

Answer (score 3):

You are asking about isolation, not really atomicity. Aerospike executes all transactions in serialised fashion per key. I.e, one one write transaction can be active on a key at any given point in time. Everyone else is made to wait. Execution order is not necessarily FIFO but serialised. Same is the case with udf too.